# Excel to Ubuntu filesystem via USB or internet?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ext4

I had machines with Ubuntu hosting a VirtualBox with Windows and Excel and if I recall correctly, I had Excel access the Ubuntu file system directly (which was ext4).

Since I usually have both an Ubuntu computer and a Windows computer running, I'd like to eliminate the need for VirtualBox. My need for Excel is only occasional. Is there a way to have the Windows machine's Excel access the Ubuntu ext4 file system via USB or even the internet?

This would be far more convenient than VirtualBox.

Comment: You can create a Samba share on you Ubuntu system to make some directory of your file system available a as a network drive for Windows machines. Of course this can be accessed only when the Ubuntu system is running.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the **wine** windows emulator is able to run excel directly in linux.

Just run the office setup after **wine** is installed.